# ASP.NET MVC: Upload XML string from browser memory with progressbar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, post, progress-bar

I have a variable in javascript containing a string of XML data that I want to upload to a server running ASP.NET MVC.

It works just fine using jQuery.post method. My problem is that the data weights about 5 megabytes so this process could be rather long depending on the bandwidth available between the client and the server. As of now, in the user's perspective, the process feels like nothing is happening because there is no feedback whatsoever.

This upload is part of a workflow in which other somewhat lenghty steps are included, namely to extract the XML from a device. These steps report realtime feedback to the user thanks to the [jQuery Progressbar](http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/20/jquery-progress-bar-11/) and some client side events. It would make sense to include the upload in the same process and use some similar reporting mechanism.

Any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance!

Marc Lacoursiere
RooSoft Computing inc.

Comment: Storing 5MB of XML data on the client seems like a bad idea.  Is it really necessary to store *all* that XML on the client at once?

Comment: I recieve the data from a device and I need to send it to the server for it to be stored in a database.

I could parse the XML in javascript on client side and send less data but it seems like a complicated operation to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the data into multiple pieces (e.g. 50 kB) and then calculate the progress on the client.

Comment: Interesting idea... I will try this for sure if I cannot find an easier way.

Thanks a lot!